# my windows 10 dell is not letting me close an app even though its been uninstalled

Tags: windows

I downloaded an app named audacity for singing I uninstalled it successfully but the app is still in the taskbar and it wont let me remove it I've tried clicking the remove button when you hover over the window but it wont get out of my taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

I see other guys providing info on how to kill the process, let me know if I understood wrong but it seems to understand that the app is uninstalled and not running anymore, the issue is with the icon in the taskbar you are not able to unpin ,correct?

Try to open this path:
%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

(note some folder in that path are hidden so change folder options to show hidden files and folders and protected system files)

Once you are in that path, you should see all the links to the apps that are pinned.
Delete the one related to Audacity.

Probably the icon will be still there in the taskbar, click it, windows should ask you if you want to remove it, reply yes, it should disappear

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting?
If it's still running, follow these steps.
Open cmd as administrator and enter this command.

```
taskkill /im audacity* /f /t
```

If you see an error, try entering the audacity app process name. You can find this using Task Manager or '`Tasklist`' command.

After that, open Task Manager, go to the Startup tab, disable the audacity app if you see it there.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the methods mentioned in the following link. If it still not working, I would suggest you to remove it from the taskbar through windows safe mode, which will remove all the dependencies that may block the uninstallation in the regular mode.

https://www.totaluninstaller.com/program-uninstall-center/uninstall-audacity-app-effective-guides/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode